# IBM Worklight - Missing driver error when invoking adapter procedure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or <br>project \/newapp"
   ],<br>
   "info": [
   ],<br>
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Why is this error being encountered?

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Please always mention some background information: Worklight version, whether you've read the provided IBM Worklight training modules, what is it that you are trying to do... Help us help you.

---

Right now it seems to me like you are trying to execute a SQL adapter procedure that tries to communicate with some database backend. For the SQL adapter to be able to do so, it is required to supply the Worklight Server with the MySQL Connector/J driver, so it will know how to "talk with" a MySQL-type database.

If you haven't read yet, [please read the SQL Adapter training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf).
Pay attention to slide 5.

You need to download the driver and place its .jar file in the `your-project\server\lib` folder.